# Is this a paradox in the Cantor set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a previous question here [Can we define the Cantor Set in this way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240195/369757)

we defined a family of sets $ \left\{ C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3,\dots \right\}$

We can call this set $S_1$ , where the values of these elements is

$C_0 = \left\{ 0.0   \right\}$

$C_1 = \left\{ 0.0 , 0.2  \right\}$

$C_2 = \left\{ 0.0 , 0.2 ,0.02 , 0.22 \right\}$

$C_3 = \left\{ 0.0 , 0.2 ,0.02 , 0.22 ,0.002 , 0.202 ,0.022 , 0.222 \right\}$

and so on...

We can then take the union of $\bigcup S_1$ and get some countable set $X$

We will define a set  $S_2$ to be all the members of  $S_1$ that are not redundant.

$C_0$ is redundant because it can be removed from $S_1$ and the union will still be the same.

In fact all the elements of $S_1$ are redundant so our set

$\bigcup S_2 = \left\{ \not C_0,\not C_1,\not C_2,\not C_3,\dots   \right\}  = \varnothing \neq X \to$ Contradiction

We removed all the sets from the union that did not contribute any information, and all the information disappeared.

What went wrong here?

Comment: This is interesting.... I mean it shows  that removing "ALL the redundant sets" vs removing any "proper subset of redundant sets" are fundamentally 
 different operations. Lets see what the set theorists say.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that this isn't really a question about the Cantor set, just about the combinatorics of infinite sets in general.

E.g. we can recast it in terms of sets of natural numbers: let $A_n=\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, and think about $\bigcup A_n$. Or, even easier, we could just take $B_n=\{0\}$ (that's not a typo) and think about $\bigcup B_n$.

---

Now as to the answer to your question, *nothing went wrong* except your intuition for how infinite sets behave. Even though removing *any finite number* of the $A_n$s leaves the union of the rest unchanged, that's no reason to believe that removing *infinitely many* of the $A_n$s should do the same. There are lots of times we see a "phase transition" between finite behavior and infinite behavior - e.g. changing finitely many terms of a divergent series to $0$ leaves the result divergent, but if you change infinitely many terms to $0$ it might converge.

Answer (score -1):

Casting this in terms of the set of natural numbers, there seems to be no contradiction if $ \mathbb{N} \in S_1 $.

Let:$$  S_1 =  \left\{ C_m =  \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n \le m  \right\} : m \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $$ 
Then:$$C_0=  \left\{ 0 \right\}$$

$$C_1=  \left\{ 0,1 \right\}$$

$$C_2=  \left\{ 0,1,2 \right\}$$

$$\dots$$

$$ S_1 = \left\{ C_0,C_1,C_2,C_3,\dots , \mathbb{N} \right\} $$

$$ \mathbb{N} \in S_1 $$

$$\bigcup S_1 = \mathbb{N}  $$

Let:$$ S_2 = \left\{ C_n\not\subset (X \in  S_1) : n \in \mathbb{N}  \right\} $$

Then:$$ S_2 = \left\{ \not C_0,\not C_1,\not C_2,\not C_3,\dots , \mathbb{N} \right\} $$

$$S_2 = \left\{\mathbb{N} \right\} $$

$$\bigcup S_2 = \mathbb{N}  $$

It only gets ugly if $ \mathbb{N} \notin S_1 $